# Fortran 8- and 16-bit Unit Numbers

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to use 8-bit and 16-bit unit numbers when calling `Open`, or during read/write. If possible, how would one specify the correct declaration?

Comment: Hm, this seems to be working for me on gfortran. I've used both `-fdefault-integer-8` and `integer*8`. What have you tried that failed?

Comment: @Ross 8-bit not 8-byte. Also, changing default value might theoretically be something different than passing a non-default kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is allowed to use integers of any kind to reference an external unit.  In Fortran 2008 (but similar is given back to Fortran 90) the rule for an *external-file-unit* (R902) is merely "*scalar-int-expr*".

There are things to note, however.  First, the units that exist are processor dependent: the processor is entitled to say that a unit number must be representable by default integer.  Second, it's the *value* of the expression that is important in the file connection and data transfer statements: an external unit referenced in an `open`, `close`, `read`, `write` or `inquire` statement by `15_int16` is the same as that referenced by `15_int32` (and the same as `15`).

This latter point means that it isn't important how the unit numbers are expressed.

```
open(15_int16, ...)
write(15) ...
write(15_int8) ...
write(15_int32) ...
write(15_int64) ...
```

are all appropriate (for when those kind numbers are valid).

---

In Fortran 95 when doing inquire by file/unit the variable given by the `number=` specifier had to be of default integer.  That restriction is no longer in place.